# Is "Indicant" same as "Indicator"?

Tags: word-choice, semantics

I was reading my class textbook, International Management: Strategic Opportunities & Cultural Challenges, where it said

> He solved this problem in a very clever way by devising several
>   objective indicants of time, ones that did not rely on language or
>   self-report.

It feels like the word *indicants* here are more synonymous with the word *standards* than with the word *indicators*. Is the book just using flowery language here? Why didn't it just use *standards* or *indicators* instead of *indicants*?

Comment: I'd never heard of ***indicant*** before now, but a quick look at the full OED suggests your source is actually *misusing* the term. OED's first definition has it as an adjective *(=indicative)*. The noun usage is specifically noted as being in the *medical* domain, *that which indicates the remedy or treatment suitable* *(**indication**)*, for which their last citation is 1701.

Comment: Google Books has [40 instances of "objective indicants"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22objective+indicants%22#q=%22objective+indicants%22&safe=off&tbm=bks&start=30), against [over 35,000 instances of "objective indicators"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22objective+indicators%22). I think all those first 40 are "errors".

Comment: Indeed, such are the origins: in Latin, *indicant* is present active participle (closest English equivalent being "pointing", as in "the sign pointing to the inn"); *indicator* is a masculine agent noun, "pointers are rude people". But Father Time has a habit of messing up our nice clean explanations...

Comment: So the book is just using flowery language? Perhaps the authors wanna show off their power of word choice.